# Remove &nbsp; in post content

Tags: php, html

I have been trying to figure out since yesterday on how I can remove the code `&nbsp;` on my post. In the WYSIWYG editor it shows spaces, but once after I publish my post, it shows words sticking together and also replacing the space with `&nbsp`. I have screenshot of my problem.

**Here is a screenshot of the publish post/article**

[image]

**Here is the screenshot when I tried inspecting the element. As you can &nbsp keeps adding within the paragraph element**

[image]

Comment: Was this content pasted it from another source (even Word), or did you type it directly in the Wordpress editor? If it was pasted, does it help if you retype it?

Comment: I think so, client seems to be copy and pasting from another editor like MS word. I tried retyping it on the Wordpress editor and it does not show the *nbsp code on the publish post. What seems to be problem when copying and pasting the content?

Comment: How did you go with this?

Answer (score 1):

As per comments on the original post, it appears this is as a result of copying text from another source.

Unfortunately, copying and pasting can bring across whatever junk the source editor decides to include. MS Word has typically been terrible at this; Wordpress now does a pretty good job at cleaning it up but it's not always perfect.

Rather than pasting directly, I'd suggest using the "Paste as Text" button on the Wordpress editor toolbar (it looks like a T on a clipboard, next to the text colour option):

[image: Paste as text toolbar button]

Alternatively, pasting the text into a text-only editor such as Notepad before copying it again and then pasting into Wordpress will also do the trick.